# FileHelpers Take Limit?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am wondering while it is reading in a stream from a file can you tell it to only take x amount of rows? Say if you want 100 rows from the file can you tell it to only take the first 100 rows(ignoring the first row as it would be the header). Even if the file had 200 rows?

Comment: With almost 7k, you should at least know how to tag a question. What language, platform? From your comments I see this is C#, but do us all a favour and tag it as such.

Comment: If you read the filehelper tag you will see that it is for is a .net library written in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [FileHelperAsyncEngine](http://www.filehelpers.com/quick_start_async.html) which processes the records one by one.

```
FileHelperAsyncEngine engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine(typeof(Customer)); 
engine.BeginReadFile("TestIn.txt"); 

int recordCount = 0;

foreach (Customer cust in engine)
{    
    // your code here 
    Console.WriteLine(cust.Name);

    recordCount++;
    if (recordCount > 100)
        break; // stop processing 
}

engine.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

A "file stream" doesn't have "rows".

Certain devices allow you to "seek" (go to a specific, random offset in the file).  This can certainly save you time.  But unless the file has a fixed format, you can't know exactly which byte offset corresponds to which logical row.

Q:
What platform, programming language and file type are you talking about, anyway?

Comment: By that I meant that while it is reading in the stream it is creating it into objects(one row == one object). So while it is doing this I thought maybe you can tell it to stop after it has created so many objects. Filehelpers is a .net library(I am using C#)